# Got Error while using array of objects in sequilize.js?

Tags: sequelize.js

While I tried to compile this code

```js
const UserDetail = connection.define('user_detail', {
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        len: [6, 50],

    },
    about: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    position: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    birth: [{
        year: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        location: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },
    }]
});
```

It throws this error

```js
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[object Object], `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, P' at line 1
```

What the good way to create array of object? I google this question but can't find solution and the previous one on Stack Overflow I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be an "array" you can use a different related table, or you can define the fields as:

```
birth_year: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
},
birth_location: {
  type: Sequelize.TEXT,
  allowNull: false,
},
```